# SharePoint 2010 - Enable all logging timer jobs. Performance?

Tags: performance, timer-jobs, logging

I found an interesting article about the logging timer jobs in SharePoint 2010.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg512103.aspx#bk_splog

In this article, it is stating that all the following timer jobs are disabled by default.

**Timer jobs:**

- **Diagnostic Data Provider: Event Log**
  (Collects Windows Event Log entries and stores the data in the logging database.
  10 minutes)
- **Diagnostic Data Provider: Performance Counters - Database Servers**
  (Collects Performance Monitor Counters data on database servers and stores the data in the logging database. 5 minutes **Important:** The timer service account must have sufficient permission to collect counters on the database server. The account should be a member of the Performance Monitor Users (PMU) group.)
- **Diagnostic Data Provider: Performance Counters - Web Front Ends**
  (Collects Performance Monitor Counters data on front-end Web servers and stores the data in the logging database.
  5 minutes)
- **Diagnostic Data Provider: SQL Blocking Queries Diagnostic Data**
  (Collects data associated with blocked SQL queries and stores the data in the logging database. 15 seconds)
- **Provider: SQL DMV Diagnostic Data Provider: SQL Memory DMV Diagnostic**
  (Collects SQL Dynamic Management Views (DMV) data and stores the data in the logging database. 30 minutes)
- **Data Provider: Trace Log** (Collects Trace Log entries and stores the usage data in the logging database and stores the data in the logging database. 10 minutes)

My question is now: Is it a performance problem to activate all these timer jobs?

[Technet: Timer job reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff808317.aspx)

Comment: A good way to answer this question would be to explain what each of these jobs is for, and what it does when enabled. This would give a better understanding of the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse any additional logging will increase resource using. Is very hard question will it suitable for you. It depends on your servers logical and phisical topology and hardware.